# Javascript function is not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts

The attached is the my code. When I click on  'Upload more files', `addElement` function will add one browse file. It's working in IE but it's not working in Google Chrome. In Chrome when I click on the button it's not even responding.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script>

var fCount = 1;
function addElement() {

fCount++;

var fObject = document.getElementById('fileSection');
var text = 'File:';
var tag='<input type="file" name="theFile[' +  fCount +  ']" value="">';
var brk='<br>'
var o1 = document.createTextNode(text);
var o2 = document.createElement(tag);
var o3 = document.createElement(brk);

   fObject.appendChild(o3);
   fObject.appendChild(o1);
   fObject.appendChild(o2);
   fObject.appendChild(o3);

  alert("fCount" + fCount);

}

</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="pink">

<html:form action="/myActionForm" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div id="fileSection">
            Select file to upload <html:file property="theFile[0]"/><br>
            </div>
        <html:button property="bt" onclick="addElement()">Upload More files</html:button>


    <html:submit></html:submit>
    <br>
    <br>

</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide instead the rendered HTML code?! Any error in console? Is the click event fired or not?

Comment: why people not provide their console error?

Comment: This is not Struts2, it's Struts1, that's EOL (dead), and you should not use it anymore in 2014. I'd also recommend to always indent code, and to avoid using IE as a developer to test the correctness of a web application.

Comment: Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document'

This is the error i am getting when i inspect the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to pass a `tag name` to the `createElement` method. Not a element fragment. IE is always strange, may be work, but it's wrong.

The correct way is like this:

```
var tag = document.createElement('input');
tag.setAttribute('type', 'file');
tag.setAttribute('name', 'theFile[' +  fCount +  ']');
```